# Google Glass Card Constructor Undefined

Tags: java, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to display my altitude on Glass' screen using mAltText. When I call the card class, it gives me the error: "The constructor Card(new LocationHelper.LocationResult(){}) is undefined" because I have "this" as a parameter. What should I use instead of "this" in order for it to work? I have searched all day for a working example to no avail.

Can anyone offer some advice to a newbie || should I use the android textview instead of card and then inflate an XML to the view?

LocationHelper is another class in another .java file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String mAltText;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    LocationHelper locationHelper;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         this.locationResult = new LocationResult(){ 
             @Override
             public void gotLocation(Location location){

                 if(location!=null){     
                     double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                     double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                     double altitude = location.getAltitude();
                     mAltText = (Double.toString(altitude));  

                     // display on card
                     Card card = new Card(this); //Error: The constructor Card(new LocationHelper.LocationResult(){}) is undefined
                     card.setText(mAltText);
                     View cardView = card.getView();
                     setContentView(cardView);

                 }else{
                     Log.e(TAG, "Location is null.");
                 }  
             }
         };
         this.locationHelper = new LocationHelper();
         this.locationHelper.getLocation(this, this.locationResult);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Card constructor takes Context as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/Card).

So, you can pass any variable that is a subclass of Context. In your case, Activity is a good choice.

```
Card card = new Card(MainActivity.this);
```

In your code, you can't just use `this` because `this` refers to LocationResult and it's not Context.

> Can anyone offer some advice to a newbie || should I use the android textview instead of card and then inflate an XML to the view?

You can have a text view in a card. FYI, Card API is replaced by [CardBuilder](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardBuilder). If you don't have any special requirement or custom view, you can go with CardBuilder.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly; I knew it was something simple. It stemmed from my limited knowledge of what exactly "context" is. You saved the day my friend.